# Converting Markdown tables to HTML using markdown2

Tags: python, html, markdown

I'm trying to (programmatically) convert Markdown tables to HTML using [markdown2](https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2), but it's not working. I take it should because *markdown2* is supposed to be a

> complete implementation of Markdown in Python

A minimal non-working example (meant to be run in a Jupyter notebook to properly display the output):

```
import markdown2
import IPython.display

markdown_text = '''
| Tables        | Are           | Cool  |
| ------------- |:-------------:| -----:|
| col 3 is      | right-aligned | 1600 |
| col 2 is      | centered      |   12 |
| zebra stripes | are neat      |    1 |
'''

display(IPython.display.Markdown(markdown_text))

converter = markdown2.Markdown()
html = converter.convert(markdown_text)

display(IPython.display.HTML(html))
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tables aren't part of [the original Markdown specification](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax). Try [enabling](https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2#extra-syntax-aka-extensions) the [relevant extra](https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2/wiki/tables):

```py
import markdown2
import IPython.display

markdown_text = '''
| Tables        | Are           | Cool  |
| ------------- |:-------------:| -----:|
| col 3 is      | right-aligned | 1600 |
| col 2 is      | centered      |   12 |
| zebra stripes | are neat      |    1 |
'''

display(IPython.display.Markdown(markdown_text))

converter = markdown2.Markdown(extras=["tables"])  # <-- here
html = converter.convert(markdown_text)

display(IPython.display.HTML(html))
```